# Duplicate values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table called client with a primary key and a table called visits with a Foreign key client_id. The visits table has multiple rows with the same client_id. Is there a way to group the visits with the client without repeating the client name multiple times?
In the photo the client name repeats 3 times, how can i get all the values from year, month etc without repeating the client name?

The query is

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    client
    JOIN visits ON client.id = visits.id_client
```

I tried the group by and it didn't work:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: This is impossible. You may set the values which are cut off the screenshot to NULL only.

Comment: i understand, thank you.

Comment: You can't do that just with SQL. You'd have to write some PHP to process the data, keep track of where you're up to when outputting the table and decide not to echo certain cells when you don't want them to appear. You just need to think through the necessary logic and try to implement it.